# using enqueue_script in a shortcode isn't working

Tags: functions, shortcode, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm new to wordpress and I'm trying to get this to work by following the wordpress codex but I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

I have a child theme based off of a parent one, and I created a file called "functions.php" in the root directory of the child theme with FTP.  I added this code to it:

```
<?php
function my_canvas_include(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet.css');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/site.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

  $output = '';
  $output .= '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas ';
  return $output;
}

add_shortcode('my_canvas', 'my_canvas_include');
?>
```

The example here has some contrived names for the function and shortcode.  The idea, though, is that I want to include the js and stylesheet *only* on those pages I need it (by using the shortcode `[my_canvas]` when editing a page in wordpress admin) which will also output that canvas element (the styles and js will manipulate the canvas element).

Using the shortcode...mostly works.  It adds the canvas element, but I don't see the stylesheet or js file anywhere in the source, and even when i put `alert('hi')` in the js file it doesn't do anything when I use the shortcode on the page.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there another way I'm supposed to conditionally include stylesheets or scripts on only pages that need them?

Comment: Your shortcode works when I test it. The stylesheet and script loads.

Comment: Ok one question, (I've read up some more), is it loading them both into wp_footer()?  That's... not a good idea for stylesheets is it?

Comment: It isn't correct for stylesheets but as you are loading after the `<head>` has printed, you have no choice unless you want to do something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376