# Print shortcode in custom action hook not where the shortcode is entered

Tags: customization, shortcode, hooks, actions

I have added a custom action hook into my theme. I want to be able to enter a shortcode anywhere in the_content() and have the shortcode print were the custom action hook is rather then the point from where the shortcode was entered.

The shortcode displays a gallery and the custom hook in the header.

It works if I do_shortcode() directly in the action callback but the shortcode displays on all pages. So I know the hook it working but I only want the gallery to display in the header of pages that the shortcode is entered into the_content().

Comment: Your header is going to execute and print to the screen before  the content is processed. You will have to do something like this (which answers a question that is a duplicate in all but the fine details):  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376

Comment: I should add, a hack like suggested (by me :) ) in that other thread should be avoided if at possible. If you can explain what you are doing there is probably another way to go about this.

Comment: I was so busy looking for a fast, quick solution that I overlooked the load order. I ended up using a custom meta box. To was to busy focusing on a fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use a meta box:

```
// create the meta box
function dht_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'dht_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Do Header Thing' ), // meta box title
        'dht_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post' // post type or page. This adds to posts only
    );
}
function dht_cb($post) {
  $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'do_header_thing',true);
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="do_header_thing" ',checked($meta),' />';
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dht_box' );

// save the data
add_action(
  'save_post',
  function ($post_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['do_header_thing'])) {
      add_post_meta($post_id,'do_header_thing',true);
    } else {
      delete_post_meta($post_id,'do_header_thing',true);
    }
  }
);
```

Then, in your template file or on an appropriate hook use:

```
if (is_single()) {
  $obj = get_queried_object();
  $dht = get_post_meta($obj->ID,'do_header_thing',true);
  if (!empty($dht)) { 
    echo 'Yay';
  }
}
```

Very crude code but that should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a meta box, it worked perfectly...fyi I did not test you code, I used mine.

Comment: I tested the code (like most code I post here) and it does work but it _is_ very crude. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

So you call a custom action like `do_action('print_gallery');` in the header, now you want that when this action is triggered it prints the content of a shorcode inserted anywhere in the post content.

Off course, when you print `the_content()` you don't want the shortcode is printed again.

So, in the function that hooks `print_gallery` action you can insert something like this:

```
add_action('print_gallery', 'print_gallery_shortcode');

function print_gallery_shortcode() {
  if ( ! is_single() ) return;
  $shortcode_name = 'gallery';
  $content = get_queried_object()->post_content;
  if (
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches )
    && array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) && in_array( $shortcode_name, $matches[2] )
  ) {
    foreach ( $matches[2] as $i => $sc ) {
      if ( $sc == $shortcode_name ) {
        echo do_shortcode( $matches[0][$i] );
        // prevent shortcode is printed again in the post content
        add_shortcode($shortcode_name, '__return_false'); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've used the standard wordpress `[gallery]` shortcode, if you use a custom one, just replace the name of shortcode in the `$shortcode_name` variable.

Now you can insert the shortcode everywhere you want in the content and the shortcode output is printed whre you have `do_action('print_gallery')` instead of in the content.

(Of course, if the function `the_content()` is called *before* than `do_action('print_gallery')` you'll get a duplicate of shortcode: my function cannot prevent something that *already* happened..)

Note that the function **doesn't** interfere with other shortcodes inserted in the post content that are printed normally in the content.

Comment: Thanks, I took that into consideration but decided to just build a custom meta box. I worked perfectly.