# Choose to show or not show title on a template?

Tags: templates, title, content

I want to show the page title in some pages but on others I don't. I'm wondering how to do it. 
I thought about using differente content templates one with title and one without. But I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in some other way, like for example including a checkbox in the page to toggle the title.

How can I choose not to show the title in some particular pages?

Comment: Different context but I think it is the same answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113842/21376

Comment: As-written, your question cannot be reasonably answered. **What exact contexts** do you want to show (or not show) a title? And are you referring to the *HTML page* title, or the *post* title?

Comment: I think my code from the other thread can work with most cases but yes, as written a precise answer to this question is not possible.