# Clarify: Enqueueing scripts within shortcode only loads in footer?

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-script

Each time I enqueue scripts inside the shortcode handler, it ends up in the footer. It doesn't matter whether I register them first and set it to load in the header, if I enqueue inside the shortcode it goes in the footer. From what I understand this is the correct behavior - am I right?

Is there any possibility to enqueue a script from within the shortcode handler that will go in the header?

Typically I'd let it load in the footer but some JS's just refuse to work in the footer and I have to fall back on strpos or regex to look for the shortcode before enqueueing. I'm just trying to find a more efficient way. Thanks!

--Update--

As requested, here were my methods.

1. Register script

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ftrjs_admin_init' );
   function ftrjs_admin_init() {
   wp_register_script( 'lwtcountdown', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/lwt/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js', array('jquery') );
   }
   ```
2. Shortcode

   ```
   add_shortcode( 'ftrjs', 'ftrjs_callback' );
   function ftrjs_callback( $atts ) {
   wp_enqueue_script('lwtcountdown');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'lwtcounter' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'lwtstyle' );

   $out = "";
   $out .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($)
   function set_by_date() {
   $('#countdown_dashboard').stopCountDown();
   $('#countdown_dashboard').setCountDown({
       targetDate: {
       'day':      15,
       'month':    1,
       'year':     2014,
       'hour':     12,
       'min':      0,
       'sec':      0
   }
   });
   $('#countdown_dashboard').startCountDown();
   }
   )};
   </script>";
   return $out;
   }
   ```

In doing this exercise, I see now why it doesn't work because my shortcode outputs Javascript inline, before the plugin loads in the footer.

Once I pulled that out and put it into a separate JS file and enqueue that file it works.

So now, if I need to pass variables I have to use wp_localize_script.

Comment: if your js fails in the footer, then there's something wrong with your js. but the reason it has to go in the footer when enqueued in a shortcode handler is because the header has already been output and sent to the browser.

Comment: If you really must load a script in the header by means of a shortcode you need to do something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376 But that is labor intensive. I would not do it if there is another way.

Comment: @Milo I understand what you're saying, I'm no JS expert so I can't say if there is something wrong or not. Most times I'm enqueing a jQuery plugin. The latest one I tried was a jQuery countdown timer and it just won't work in the footer.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks! That's what I've been doing - well similar but yeah. I too am looking for a better alternative but seems like that's what I have to resort to.

Comment: It would help if you added the code you are using to enqueue your js and instantiate the plugin to your question. It's possibly an issue of noConflict wrappers or not wrapping your own js in a ready event. Also realize that there are poorly written jQuery plugins out there and it may be an issue that the plugin developer has to fix.

Comment: I still think the best way is to fix the script to load in the footer but you could do your heavy lifting in the backend and save a post meta "flag" indicating that the script needs to load. It would be more efficient.

Comment: @Milo thanks for the suggestion to include code. Through it I suddenly saw the light. Updated my original question. Thanks so much guys.