# Adding css to wp_head from shortcode

Tags: shortcode, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to add CSS to wp_head, from within the method called to render a shortcode. I know that wp_head does not take any parameters, so I'm trying to figure out the following:

The method called by WP to render the shortcode has two params, **$atts** and **$content**. What I'm trying to do is generate instance specific CSS from the **$atts** provided, and add it to the header, rather than rendering a  tag in my method, I'd like all of my CSS in  one spot (I'm adding a numerical ID to each rule, which allows custom CSS even if its the same shortcode).

The troubles I'm having:

1. I can't just pass a string to wp_head using add_actionm it requires a function
2. Because I need the $atts provided by wordpress, the function has to accept a parameter, which php 5.2 doesn't support (minimum supported php version for WP).
3. WP doesnt have a way to called something like.. content_for in rails, so I cant just append it and put it where I want.

I've tried *filters*, *actions*, *wp_add_inline_styles*, and even *globals* with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `wp_head` action is fired before the shortcode is generated via the `do_shortcode` callback of the `the_content` filter. Some solutions try to peek into the `post_content` earlier on with regex (for example via the `the_posts` filter) to check if it contains any shortcodes. You should try to search this site to find these "peek" solutions.

Comment: In essence, you need this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376