# Conditional loading of CSS for my plugin

Tags: conditional-content

I'd like to continually load the stylesheet needed by my plugin depending on whether a particular shortcode is present on the post or page. The presence of the shortcode would indicate that the user is using the plugin on that post or page and therefore we need to load the JS and CSS. Is this possible?

Comment: Essentially, you need this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WP 3.3 you can use `wp_enqueue_*()` after `wp_head`, and enqueued scripts and styles (if not already added to the `head` of the page) would be loaded in the footer.

In short just call `wp_enqueue_script()` / `wp_enqueue_style()` in your shortcode callback:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_callback' );
function my_shortcode_callback(){

    //Shortcode does something, and generates mark-up to return
    $html = '';

    //Enqueue scripts / styles
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-script' );

    return $html;
}
```