# Load CSS files in header of Bones theme?

Tags: plugins, themes, shortcode, jquery, javascript

I'm using the [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) theme, and I'm trying to turn jQuery plugins into WordPress plugins. In the init.php file for the 'Chosen' plugin I'm converting, I've included this code:

```
function chosen(){
    wp_register_script("chosen-script",plugins_url( 'js/chosen.jquery.min.js' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script("chosen-script");
    wp_register_style("chosen-style",plugins_url( 'css/chosen.css' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style("chosen-style");
}

add_shortcode('chosen', 'chosen');
```

Google PageSpeed came back with this error:

> Put CSS in the document head (1):
>
> Link node chosen.css should be moved to the document head in
>   www.blank.com/

How can I include this CSS file in the header?

Comment: You should hook the function that registers and enqueues the scripts onto wp_enqueue_script.  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chosen' ); rather than as a shortcode.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that did it. The only problem is that now the plugin in loaded on every page of my site. With 'add_shortcode', the plugin was loaded only on pages that contained the 'chosen' shortcode. Is there a way without 'if' statements to include the plugin only on specific pages?

Comment: In regards to my last question, this is how I would load it on a specific page: `if (is_page('to-do_list'))`

Comment: To dynamically load stylesheets in the `head` based on a shortcode, you will have to [do something like this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376) which is admittedly a bit processing heavy.

Answer (score 1):

By the time the shortcode is evaluated as part of `the_content` the header of the site has already been assembled. This makes it impossible to load scripts or styles in the header anymore.

As [s_ha_dum suggests](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode/101515#101515) you could pre-process the whole post in the head of the file, but that would probably consume more resources than indiscriminately adding the js+css files to the header.

Another, also quite elaborate, approach would be to hook into [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and set a postmeta flag indicating whether the shortcode is used in the post. You could then read the flag while still in the head and include the js+css files.