# Is it possible to include the add_filter() function within a shortcode function

Tags: filters, shortcode

I am trying to pass content to the 'google_dfp_ad_slot' filter. Can this be done within a shortcode funcion?

```
/**
     * Shortcode function to dynamically add google dfp ads to inline content and widgets
     *
     * [fopconnect_ad is_page="true" page="about"]
     *   {JS}googletag.defineSlot('/6111408/FOPC_All_LeaderBoard_728x90', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1398288352265-0').addService(googletag.pubads());{/JS}
     *   {HTML}<div id='div-gpt-ad-1342652501811-0' style='width:160px; height:600px;'><script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1342652501811-0'); });</script></div>{/HTML}
     * [/fopconnect_ad]
     *
     * @param  array $atts    shortcode attributes
     * @param  string $content
     * @return sting
     */



    add_shortcode( 'fopconnect_ad', 'fopconnect_ad_func' );
    function fopconnect_ad_func( $atts, $content ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'is_page' => false,
            'page' => '' // can be title, slug, or id
        ), $atts ) );

        preg_match("#\\{JS\\}(.*?)\\{/JS\\}#s", $content, $matches);
        $js = ( !empty( $matches[1] ) ? $matches[1] : '' );

        preg_match("#\\{HTML\\}(.*?)\\{/HTML\\}#s", $content, $matches);
        $content = ( !empty( $matches[1] ) ? $matches[1] : '' );

        if ( $is_page && is_page( explode(', ', $page) ) ) {
            add_filter( 'google_dfp_ad_slot', function( $js ) { return $js; } );
        }

        if ( $is_page && is_page( explode(', ', $page) ) ) {
            return $content;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible but you will have to be aware of timing issues. Your shortcode will have to execute before whatever hook you are hooking into.

That is, you can't hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_head` but you should be able to hook into later hooks like `wp_footer`. I suspect that timing is the problem.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The output of that filter is located in the wp_head action hook. see below: `add_action('wp_head', 'fopconnect_head');function fopconnect_head() { apply_filters('google_dfp_ad_slot', '') } `

Comment: `wp_head` runs well before your post content. You can't hook into that hook from a shortcode without doing something very server intensive like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376)

Comment: Thanks for the example, it appears that code would be called on every request. I've decided to hook into wp_footer. One of the problems I ran into was the `$js` variable was not scoped correctly. to fix that issue i used the Use keyword: `if ( $is_page && is_page( explode(', ', $page) ) ) { add_filter('google_dfp_ad_slot', function() use($js) {return $js;});
            }`