# Loading shortcode stylesheet only when shortcode is in text widget

Tags: shortcode, css, widget-text

I would like to load shortcode stylesheet only when it will be put in text widget. Please help somebody.

Comment: Your question is not clear and seems to have several parts but I think part of the answer is here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101515/21376

Comment: In standard WordPress a shortcode in a text widget doesn't do anything, it just prints out the shortcode, it's not processed

Comment: @ s_ha_dum and Tom thanks for your response. I have found the solution :)

Comment: Then please add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to register your stylesheet with [`wp_register_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style), then load the stylesheet via [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) from within the shortcode's function, so it only loads when the shortcode is executed.

For a rundown on how this will work here's a good article. It refers to scripts, but I believe the same is true for styles: http://mikejolley.com/2013/12/sensible-script-enqueuing-shortcodes/

(Also, if you need shortcodes to run in text widgets be sure to add this to your plugin or functions.php file: `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');`)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michelle! I put wp_enqueue_style() within shortcode's function and now the stylesheet loads only when shortcode is excuted. I'm very grateful to you :)